# How to create a child process with a different name

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

I'm working with C and I need to create a child process with a name different from parent (e.g. `child_test`) How to do it in Linux with `fork()`?

Comment: Can you just change `argv[0]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`prctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) system call for this.  It has a horrible interface but if you get over that, using it for this task is rather straight forward.  Here is a minimal example.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* perror() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* NULL */
#include <sys/prctl.h>  /* prctl(), PR_SET_NAME */
#include <sys/types.h>  /* wait() */
#include <sys/wait.h>   /* wait() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* fork(), sleep() */

int
main()
{
  const char * name = "it_worked";
  switch (fork())
    {
    case 0:
      if (prctl(PR_SET_NAME, (unsigned long) name) < 0)
        perror("prctl()");
      sleep(10);
      break;
    case -1:
      perror("fork()");
      break;
    default:
      if (wait(NULL) < 0)
        perror("wait()");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

If I compile this program to an executable called `a.out` and then run `./a.out & ps`, I can observe the following

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7462 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
 7741 pts/7    00:00:00 a.out
 7742 pts/7    00:00:00 it_worked
 7743 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
```

which shows that apparently “it worked”.

Note that the name is restricted to a maximum length of 16 bytes including the terminating NUL byte.  Quoting the man page:

> Set the name of the calling thread, using the value in the location pointed to by `(char *) arg2`.  The name can be up to 16 bytes long, including the terminating null byte.  (If the length of the string, including the terminating null byte, exceeds 16 bytes, the string is silently truncated.)

Comment: Ok that works but if i give a name greater then 15 chars it will read only the first 15.. some suggestions?

Comment: @Nhoya Yes, the 16 bytes are a system limit.  I've added that to the answer.  Glad you found it useful.

Comment: @5gon12eder : Don't know why but it is not working for me,